# Java output String variable with syso.printf

Tags: java, string, printf, output

I have a String variable. Let it be

```
String name = "Paul";
```

I want to use this String in the printf. Like

```
System.out.printf("Name: %(some text here)\t age: %d", name, age);
```

Is it possible to do it? If not then what should I use?
*%s doesn't work here btw.*

Comment: why not use String.format("Name: %s \t age: ...."); ?

Comment: "_%s doesn't work here btw._" [Yes it does](https://tio.run/##LYzBCsIwDIbP21OEgrDBHII3xUdQhB3VQ1xn6bZ2Y00HInv2mk5Pyf/l/9LijNtWdiGM/tnrGuoenYMzagufNPlDR0g85kFLMHzKKpq0VbcH4KRcHpvJD4FF08AJxBV9L47MtSVAFdl@F3P1dtSYcvBUjmzQKxMXdg6wcfe1yZsUxfqoiDlna0mXEL4).

Comment: System.out.printf() is (I believe) just a wrapper over String.Format. Had you actually used a %s it should have worked (rather than the "%(some text here)"

Comment: Try to bring whole code. %s should work.

Answer (score -1):

You can use the following:

```
System.out.println("Name: "+ name+ "\t Age: "+ age);
```

Why not just try appending these. Is there any other requirement, I am missing.

Comment: Yes, I am used to using loggers on Java. Edited it. The question on this is not really clear though.